# Create-react-app - how does index.html read React application code?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm new to React and I used this explanation to build a basic React app:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

I opened a new project by:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

index.html file is located in hello-world/public and here is the content of it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, all the "React stuff" is placed in hello-world\src directory. It looks that 'hello-world\src\index.js' activates the components.

What I don't understand is how index.html "reads" the content of index.js. index.html has no html tag that leads to index.js.

I can start this application by doing "npm start". What this command does is raising a server running on localhost:3000. How can I see the application without using "npm start"?

Comment: it's because react put itself between that `<div id="root"> </div>`.

Comment: I undersand it. What I want is just to double click index.html and see the entire application (without setting up a server using 'npm start')

Comment: you mean in `dist/` folder?

Comment: @CrazySynthax to view your content by clicking just on index.html,You should use tools like webpack which will build all your react components code in a single file,which may named as bundle.min.js and then you just need to include that bundle.min.js in your index.html

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the DOM rendered on the browser (for `npm start`), it has the below script node injected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Similarly, for the production builds (`npm run build`), there is an index.html file under build folder that has a similar `script` node injected.

Example in my case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.440dcd65.js">
```

Therefore, I tend to think that the script node injection is done by the `react-scripts` library or from one of it's dependencies.

Also, to run the app without a web server, the below should work:

1. Have `"homepage": "./"` defined in the package.json
2. Run a production build (`npm run build`)
3. Launch the `index.html` directly from the `build` folder.

**Edited:**

The configurations under `./node_modules/react-scripts/config` appears to takes care of the `<script>` node injection.

Example: `./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js` has,

```
// Generates an index.html file with the <script> injected.
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: paths.appHtml,
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bundle all your codes in single js file,for doing that you can use tools like webpack.

Suppose You have project structure like this:-

```
Project
-src
    -app.js
-index.html
-package.json
-node-modules
```

**You need to add  webpack.config.js** :- in your root directory which will contain some certain configurations to bundle your codes.

`webpack.config.js` will look alike this:-

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');
DEV_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'src');

var config = {
    entry:DEV_DIR + '/app.js',
    output:{
        path:BUILD_DIR,
        filename:'bundle.min.js',
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.jsx?/,
                include:DEV_DIR,
                loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude:/node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
};
module.exports = config;
```

**Add a .babelrc file in your root directory:-**

```
{
"presets": ["react","es2015","stage-1"]
}
```

after that In your root directory run command:-`webpack`
that will create a dist folder which will contain your bundle.min.js.

**Edits in your index.html** :-

```
<script src = "dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-core": "^6.25.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"webpack": "^3.4.1",
},
```

I know this is quite a big but in my opinion you will have to go through this process while developing in react,so better to go through this in the beginning.